# Use of .toWindow in DalekJS

Tags: dalekjs

I'm trying to access a 2nd window opened by my test code:

```
.click('.footer-content li:nth-child(thisItem)')
.toWindow('http://thisDomain.com')
.assert.title().to.contain(thisTitle)
.toParentWindow()
```

I can see the correct page open in the browser, but the test still returns the title of the originating page.  Am I using .toWindow correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it the name of the window, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name

Comment: 1.  Is there a way to assign a window name to the .click statement?  The <a href> includes a target="_blank" argument.
2.  Is there a way to capture the URL from the <a href> tag and then use a new .open statement?  Something like var myLink =  ('.footer-content li:nth-child(7) a[href]') and .open(myLink)?  Eventually I would expand this into a for loop over all the li items.